# How to understand "in it" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

> "... It's forty-ten, forty-ten to Slytherin and Pucey has the Quaffle ..."
>
> Harry could hear Luna's ludicrous lion hat roaring amidst the Gryffindor cheers and felt heartened; only thirty points **in it**, that was nothing, they could pull back easily. ....
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

The word '**in**' confuses me here. I feel "*only thirty points **behind***" makes more sense. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Only _____ in it' in this context is very idiomatic to the circumstances of a game or contest.

> only thirty points in it.

would be understood to mean

> only thirty points between them.

Literally 'in it' makes very little sense. In what? Presumably 'it' is the game's score, but if you tried to say

> only thirty points in the score

it wouldn't meant the same thing at all.

So I guess it's just one of those idioms you have to learn.

Comment: Is this BrE? I'm a native speaker of AmE and that phrase is not familiar to me.

Comment: I would interpret it as *only thirty points in (the game / the game's score) so far*. More often, however, I don't hear *in* ***it*** but simply *in*. As in: *they were only thirty points in, and already there was a significant lead*.

Comment: @JasonBassford What's "they were only thirty points in" supposed to  mean?

Comment: Yes it's probably specific to British English. I can assure you my interpretation is correct and Jason Bassford's is not. It is referring to the difference in the score.